# While creating sequenceFile getting ERROR nativeio.NativeIO: Unable to initialize NativeIO libraries

Tags: apache-spark

I am using standalone spark and while running a program which writes a sequence file using the pair RDD and I am getting below error:

```
ERROR nativeio.NativeIO: Unable to initialize NativeIO libraries
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: workaroundNonThreadSafePasswdCalls
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO.initNative(Native Method)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO.<clinit>(NativeIO.java:58)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:653)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:509)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:286)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:385)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:364)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:555)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.<init>(SequenceFile.java:892)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:393)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:354)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:476)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:58)
at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.open(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:980)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:974)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Following is the the code that I am using:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import scala.Tuple2;
 import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
 import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
 import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat;

 public class BasicSaveSequenceFile {

   public static class ConvertToWritableTypes implements     PairFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Text, IntWritable> {
public Tuple2<Text, IntWritable> call(Tuple2<String, Integer> record) {
  return new Tuple2(new Text(record._1), new IntWritable(record._2));
}
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 2) {
  throw new Exception("Usage BasicSaveSequenceFile [sparkMaster] [output]");
    }
String master = args[0];
String fileName = args[1];

    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(
  master, "basicloadsequencefile", System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), System.getenv("JARS"));
List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> input = new ArrayList();
input.add(new Tuple2("coffee", 1));
input.add(new Tuple2("coffee", 2));
input.add(new Tuple2("pandas", 3));
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> rdd = sc.parallelizePairs(input);
JavaPairRDD<Text, IntWritable> result = rdd.mapToPair(new ConvertToWritableTypes());
result.saveAsHadoopFile(fileName, Text.class, IntWritable.class, SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
}
}
```

I have added all the dependencies in pom.xml. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the version of spark_core jar to 1.3.1 from 1.1.0 in pom.xml. Also, removed dependency on hadoop-common jar from pom.xml.
It worked for me!!!